# Airflow: what is SubDagOperator success based on?

Tags: airflow

In Airflow, what is a SubDagOperator's success based on? From the Airflow docs: `marking success on a SubDagOperator does not affect the state of the tasks within`. But do all tasks within a SubDagOperator have to succeed for it to record success after a run? Or is it entirely separate from the state of its nested tasks? Is there a way to change its success rules?

For instance, let's say in case 1, a SubDagOperator task instance fails without any of the nested tasks being queued (e.g. an SQLAlchemy error). In case 2, nested task1 fails, but task1.trigger_rule is set to `ALL_DONE`, which triggers task2, and task2 succeeds.

1. Would Airflow mark case 2 as a success or a failure of the SubDagOperator task instance?
2. If case 2 is a failure, is there a way to distinguish between a failure like case 1 and a failure like case 2?

Comment: My observations suggest that case 2 is a definitive failure (i.e. if a single node within a subdag fails, the subdag itself is marked as failure). I think question 2 can be solved using branching and xcoms, but it would be great to be able to alter success/failure rules for subdags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subdag task success or failure depends on the inner dag's success or failure (like when you zoom into it, there's a circle above the run). I believe that it's if all final tasks are successful or skipped the dag is successful.

Comment: From [the code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/97a429f9d0cf740c5698060ad55f11e93cb57b55/airflow/jobs/backfill_job.py#L627) it seems like _any_ failing task, even if not final, will cause the subdag task to fail.  Even though the inner dag run is marked successful

Comment: @thehouse I would expect it to use a scheduler_job and not a backfill_job; though I'm not sure why the success criteria might differ.